Scene added on top of another ends up "below" in Phaser 3
I have a Scene in which I call my UI, and display a sprite.
MainGame.js
export default class MainGame extends Phaser.Scene
{
    constructor ()
    {
        super('MainGame');
        this.sprite;
    }
    create {   
        this.scene.launch('UI');
        this.sprite = this.add.sprite(0, 45, 'mysprite');
        this.sprite.anims.play({key: 'idle'}, true);   
    }
}

In my UI.js I have:
export default class UI extends Phaser.Scene
{
    constructor ()
    {
        super({key: 'UI'});
    }

    init ()
    {
        this.scene.moveUp();
    }

    create ()
    {
        //
    }
}

Yet my UI (health bar etc..) is below anything I put on the Scene of MainGame.js
Edit:
Winner_joiner pointed me in the right direction: I had another Scene in my main.js like so :
scene: [ Preloader, UI, Intro, MainGame ]

The proper way to do it is indeed to specify how Scenes should be placed instead of kinda guessing.

Interesting that should not happen, can you add your gameconfig into your question? Since my reconstruction of your problem work as expected.

Depending on your code a fast solution could be, simply calling the function moveAbove in the UI Scene (link to the documenation)
...
init(){
    this.scene.moveAbove( 'MainGame', 'UI' );
}
...


But actually your described code, should also work. Except the moveUp function call, here a parameter is missing.(link to the documentation)


Thank you, that was indeed an issue of how scenes are organized between them.  moveup() wasnt the proper way to do it so thats a good call.
